# Remove double apostrophes if there nothing within using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Ideally, via a RegEx, I need to be able to remove double apostrophes when they exist between alpha characters such as `Test''s` but not when they are between a white space like `!= ''`

Is there any way I can achieve this using Javascript and RegEx?

I have tried => `.replace("\'\'", "\'")` which solves the first problem but not the second.

Comment: Use a word boundary, `/\b''\b/g`. Or, between letters: ``/(?<=\p{L})''(?=\p{L})/gu`` or ``/(?<=[a-zA-Z])''(?=[a-zA-Z])/g``

Comment: Just a word of caution, because I'm **suspicious** about your question... In YAML files, you can express single quotes *within* a single-quoted string by writing `''`: https://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/configuration/yaml.html. Just in case your question is actually about reading a YAML file, and you're misunderstanding how the data is being represented...

Comment: Or maybe your question has got nothing to do with YAML/some other markup that's doubling the single-quotation marks to escape them, in which case please ignore me :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That's a python question.

Comment: @Cerbrus That is a *regex* question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use some capturing groups, and repace the content between the capturing groups:

```js
const str = "Test''s != ''";
const result = str.replace(/(\w)''(\w)/, "$1'$2");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try that:

```
/(?<=\w)''(?=\w)/gm;
```

it will check if the apostrophes  pairs are withing words and replace those by single apostrophe.

```js
const regex = /(?<=\w)''(?=\w)/gm;
const str = `Test''s but not when they are between a white space like != ''`;
console.log( str.replace(regex, `'`));
```

Comment: This is close but when i run it, but Test''s is still Test''s => `.replace("/(?<=\w)''(?=\w)/gm", "'")`

Comment: @Milan: You're putting quotes around the regex. `.replace("/` should be `.replace(/`. Both Rizwan and my answers work.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that but i get a bunch of latex errors [\] etc